# MYSQL insert into on duplicate key value

Tags: php, mysql, sql, linux

I have two tables X and Y. Both of them have the column 'name' in common.

Columns of X are

1. id(Auto increment) - primary key
2. name
3. email
4. value.

Columns of Y are

1. id(Auto increment) - primary key
2. name
3. sex
4. salary

There are some rows in X which are not present in Y. I want to insert those missing rows into Y. Along with that I also want to update the existing records in Y which have the same name as records in X.

I am trying to run the following query.

```
INSERT INTO Y (name, sex, salary) 
SELECT X.name, 'FEMALE' AS sex, '1000' AS salary 
FROM X LEFT JOIN Y ON X.name=Y.name 
WHERE X.email LIKE '%@test.com' 
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE sex='MALE';
```

But when I run this query, instead of updating the existing records with same name in table Y, it inserts new ones.

So I wanted to know does "On DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE" only compare using the primary keys. Is it possible to give any different column(name) in that clause.

Comment: did you configure a unique index for the tables?  add a new unique index and add the columns that will be unique and then it will update accordingly without creating a new record.

Comment: Is `name` your primary key? Assuming not (and it makes no sense that sex and salary would be) then it will insert as you're not defining the key value, so won't match as a dupe.

Comment: "name" is not the primary key. So does it mean it's not possible to update the records using ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your query like below. The comparison happens on primary key column or on unique constraint on a (group of) column(s). If a row is inserted that would cause a duplicate value in a `UNIQUE index or PRIMARY KEY`, an `UPDATE` of the old row is performed. See [Documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html) for more information.

```
INSERT INTO Y (name, sex, salary) 
SELECT X.name, 'FEMALE' AS sex, '1000' AS salary 
FROM X LEFT JOIN Y ON X.name=Y.name 
WHERE X.email LIKE '%@test.com' 
AND Y.name IS NULL
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE Y.sex='MALE';
```

(OR) separate them in two queries like `INSERT`

```
INSERT INTO Y (name, sex, salary) 
SELECT X.name, 'FEMALE' AS sex, '1000' AS salary 
FROM X LEFT JOIN Y ON X.name = Y.name 
WHERE X.email LIKE '%@test.com' 
AND Y.name IS NULL;
```

Perform `UPDATE`

```
UPDATE Y 
JOIN X ON X.name = Y.name
 SET Y.sex='MALE'
WHERE X.email LIKE '%@test.com';
```

Comment: I tried the first approach. As expected, It only inserted rows from X, which are missing in Y. But for the rows already present in Y with the same name, it didn't update those values. Is it possible to update the existing records also in the same query based on the name column(Not a primary key)?

Comment: @Pattu, as said `On Dup Key` does the comparison on key column and here `name` is not a key column. So either you make `name` as key column (or) resort to second approach by separating the insert/update.

Comment: I follow the second approach then. Thanks for the clarification.